# Why dedicated ADDMOD opcode?

Tags: evm, opcode

Is the ADDMOD that commonly used that we needed to create a specific opcode for it? Why couldn't we simply use the ADD opcode + the MOD opcode together?

The same question is also valid for the MULMOD opcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ADDMOD and MULMOD opcodes have a specificity talked about in [the yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf).

> All intermediate calculations of this operation are not subject to the
> 2^256 modulo.

This means that you can do arithmetic above the 2^256 bits limitation as their implementation ([opAddmod](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/instructions.go#L173), [opMulmod](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/instructions.go#L183)) actually operates on Big Integers internally and only returns the result. As the modulo value cannot be above 2^256, the result cannot overflow.

Take this example :

```
function classicAddMod() public view returns (uint256 rvalue) {

    uint256 MAX_INT = 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff;

    assembly {
        rvalue := mod(add(MAX_INT, 1), 10)
    }
}
```

Where `add(MAX_INT, 1)` causes an overflow, wrapping the value back to 0. Which modulo 10 is still 0. Now, MAX_INT is actually 11579208923731619542357098500868790785326998466564056403945758400791312963993**5**, that value + 1 modulo 10 should give a result of 6.

The following version with ADDMOD actually computes it right, as it avoids the overflow by never putting the intermediate result of the addition into a 256 bit variable (*i.e.,* the 2^256 modulo) :

```
function opAddMod() public view returns (uint256 rvalue) {

    uint256 MAX_INT = 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff;

    assembly {
        rvalue := addmod(MAX_INT, 1, 10)
    }
}
```

This one does return the correct result `6` for the aforementioned reasons. Mulmod has a similar behavior.