# How to make submod in evm assembly?

Tags: evm, opcode, huff

I've been playing with [huff](https://huff.sh/) language (assembly for EVM) and tried creating a macro for subtraction modulo n.

At first, I thought it would be easy since addmod(a,n-b,n) would do the job, but this isn't the case since [all intermediate calculations of this operation are not subject to the 2^256 modulo.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/127746/why-dedicated-addmod-opcode)

and resulting a+n-b as negative number such as -2 would not give the correct representation.

So my question is: does somebody have an idea of the algorithm needed to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I did it, but anyway want to hear other thoughts:

```
#define macro SUB_MOD() = takes (0) returns (0) {
    // a - b % n = a + (n-b) % n
    0x44 calldataload     // [number3] // load third 32 bytes onto the stack - (n)

    0x24 calldataload     // [number2] // load second 32 bytes onto the stack - (n)
    0x44 calldataload     // [number3] // load third 32 bytes onto the stack - (b)
    sub                   // [number3-number2]
    0x04 calldataload     // [number1] // load first 32 bytes onto the stack - (a)
    add                   // [number1 + (number3-number2)]
    mod                   // [number1 + (number3-number2)] mod number3
    0x00 mstore           // place [number1 + (number3-number2) % number3] in memory
    0x20 0x00 return      // return first 32 bytes (result)
}
```